# Aggregate Function with Composite key

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

```
SELECT CollMstHdr.EntryNo, CollMstHdr.Date, PartyMst.PName, SUM(CollMstDtl.Amt)
FROM CollMstHdr
  INNER JOIN CollMstDtl ON CollMstHdr.EntryNo = CollMstDtl.EntryNo
  INNER JOIN PartyMst ON CollMstHdr.SPartyCd = PartyMst.PartyCd
group by CollMstHdr.EntryNo, CollMstHdr.Date, PartyMst.PName
```

I want Sum of Amt according to CollMstHdr.EntryNo and  CollMstHdr.Date ,I have EntryNo And Date Both Primary Key but Getting Amt Sum according to EntryNo only.
How to use Group By Clouse When we have two column as primary kays.

Comment: Please explain what you need. __First__ you say you want the sum per `EntryNo` __and__ `Date`, __then__ you say you want the sum per `EntryNo` __only__.

Answer (score 0):

First perform joining as per your table structure.
Then put columns in **select and group by** clause for which you want to perform grouping.

like if you want grouping on EntryNo and Date then do this :

```
SELECT CollMstHdr.EntryNo, CollMstHdr.Date, SUM(CollMstDtl.Amt)
FROM CollMstHdr
  INNER JOIN CollMstDtl ON CollMstHdr.EntryNo = CollMstDtl.EntryNo
  INNER JOIN PartyMst ON CollMstHdr.SPartyCd = PartyMst.PartyCd
group by CollMstHdr.EntryNo, CollMstHdr.Date
```

if you want grouping on EntryNo only, do this :

```
SELECT CollMstHdr.EntryNo, SUM(CollMstDtl.Amt)
FROM CollMstHdr
  INNER JOIN CollMstDtl ON CollMstHdr.EntryNo = CollMstDtl.EntryNo
  INNER JOIN PartyMst ON CollMstHdr.SPartyCd = PartyMst.PartyCd
group by CollMstHdr.EntryNo
```

Comment: I want the sum per EntryNo and Date.

Comment: then use first query ... which i have already specified in my answer... please your requirement is different .. please clarify it.